# Reading File, Trying to Display Encrypted Message from a file

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

#include "Encrypt.h"

int main() {
std::string Choose;
std::cout << "Please enter write or read(Lower Case Only): ";
std::getline(std::cin, Choose);
if (Choose == "write") {
    std::string Sentence;
    std::string SecurityKey;
    std::string TextFile;

    std::cout << "Enter Your sentence that you wish to be encrupted" << std::endl << "Sentence: ";
    std::getline(std::cin, Sentence);
    std::cout << std::endl << "Secuirty Key Disclaimer Never forget what secruity \nkey you used otherwise your message will be lost forever" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Secuirty Key: ";
    std::getline(std::cin, SecurityKey);

    std::string message = encrypt(Sentence, SecurityKey);
    std::cout << "Encrypted: " << std::endl << message;
    std::cout << "\nDecrypted: " << decrypt(message, SecurityKey) << std::endl;

    std::cout << "Enter a title for text Document: ";
    std::getline(std::cin, TextFile);
    TextFile = TextFile + ".txt";
    std::ofstream out(TextFile);
    out << message;
    out.close();
}
else if (Choose == "read") {
    std::string NameOfFile;
    std::getline(std::cin, NameOfFile);
    NameOfFile = NameOfFile + ".txt";
    std::string STRING;
    std::ifstream infile;
    infile.open(NameOfFile);
    while (!infile.eof)
    {
        getline(infile, STRING);
    }
    infile.close();
    std::string S_Key;
    std::getline(std::cin, S_Key);
    std::cout << "\nDecrypted: " << decrypt(STRING, S_Key) << std::endl;
}
else {
    std::cout << "There are only 2 Options.... (lower Case Only)" << std::endl;
}


system("PAUSE");
}
```

My problem is its not reading the file how it is Encrypting it could this be because of the .eof() reading the file differently to how the program is Encrypting it, .. Its not reading the file Correctly how do i work around this?

If anyone is Interested here is the Encrypt.h

---

```
std::string encrypt(std::string msg, std::string key) {

std::string tmp(key);
while (key.size() < msg.size())
    key += tmp;


for (std::string::size_type i = 0; i < msg.size(); ++i)
    msg[i] ^= key[i];
return msg;
}
std::string decrypt(std::string msg, std::string key) {
return encrypt(msg, key);
}
```

Comment: Furthermore, please define your question further than "not working" and "having problems"

Comment: There are tons of questions here on eof and file reading, I suggest you do a search first.

Comment: "(Lower Case Only): " it developer friendly, not user friendly. Just convert the user input to lowercase and you do not need to display a requirement and it will be easier for the user.